# SIGUSR1 in Linux

Tags: c

Please help my SIGUSR1 is not being received and I do not know what is wrong. I am doing this for practice in Linux. I exit the process in using ctrl+z and then type in kill -SIGUSR1  but the signal is not being received.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>



void sig_handler(int signo){

    switch(signo)
    case SIGUSR1:
    printf("Hello\n");
    exit(0);

}
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    printf("PID: %i\n", getpid());



    while(1)
    {
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
    printf("Error\n");    
    }
    sleep(2);
    }


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Huh. I've never seen switch used with a single expression statement before. I didn't even know that was possible. Anyways... you should only set your signal handler once, instead of in an infinite loop. Also, you can't safely call `printf()` from a signal handler. See `man signal-safety` for details.

Comment: Please indent your code properly... Use auto-formatting of your IDE, or use some online C code formatter if you have simpler editor without auto-formatting/auto-indentation feature.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `{}` with your switch case. I am not sure it is doing what you think it is doing, depending on what you think it is doing.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. You must provide a [mcve], without it, your question is off-topic. As a new user, also take the [tour] and study [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps

> step 1 :    run in background

```
bash# ./a.out &
[1] 4338 
# PID: 4338
```

> step 2:    issue SIGUSR1 from bash to the pid

```
   bash# kill -10 4338
   10 is for SIGUSR1
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking -- a suspended process (the result of pressing Ctrl-Z in the terminal, which makes the process receive a SIGSTP) does not run and cannot do anything.

Comment: You don't have to memorize signal numbers (or PIDs). You can just say `kill -USR1 %1` to send SIGUSR1 to the first background job (the `[1]` in `[1] 4338`).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider ^Z sends TSTP, not STOP.

Comment: or kill -l to get the number list

Comment: @melpomene Ah, thanks, I was not aware of that. (From what I read SIGSTP cannot be ignored, but SIGTSTP can.)

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the `ctrl+z` key causes the system to send a `TSTP` signal (`SIGTSTP`) to the running process and causes the process to suspend its execution.

Hence when you send `kill -SIGUSR1` on suspended process, `SIGUSR1` signal will be blocked.

**For example:**

> Run the process

```
$ ./a.out
PID*****: 10869
```

> Suspend the process

```
^Z  //Pressed ctrl+z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out


$ ps
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
  7529 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 10869 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 10870 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

> Send SIGUSR

```
$ kill -SIGUSR1 10869
$
/*SIGUSR is blocked until process resumes*/
```

> Resume the process.

```
$ fg
./a.out
Hello***
```

> SIGUSR is sent to process

```
$ ps
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
  7529 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 10871 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

**Solution:**

Use `&` to run your process in background and send `SIGUSR1` signal as below.

```
$ ./a.out &
[1] 11400
$ PID*****: 11400



$kill -SIGUSR1 11400

$Hello***
$
[1]+  Done                    ./a.out
```